# Read information from text file and display in listbox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to figure out how to have one form where the user writes in the information they want to see on another form in a listbox. basically the user would write in the details that they want (title, author, stock, price, fiction or nonfiction) and then would press record details and the program would search a text file for those values and then another form would come up with a listbox where they would see all those selected books.

Here is the code I have so far and it basically reads the text file information and stores it into an array:

```
    Dim Title As String
    Dim Author As String
    Dim Stock As Integer
    Dim Price As Double
    Dim Fiction As String
    Dim NonFiction As String

Private Sub btnRecord_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRecord.Click


    ''Read the information into a string''
    Dim objReader As New StreamReader("C:\Users\Books.txt")
    Dim fileString As String = objReader.ReadToEnd()
    objReader.Close()
    objReader.Dispose()

    ''Concert string into array''
    Dim Array As Char() = fileString.ToCharArray()
    Array(0) = CChar("BookName")

    ''Declare the string to hold the value''
    Dim resultString As String = ","

    ''Increment each item in the string''
    Dim curChar As Char
    For i As Integer = 0 To (Array.Length - 1)
        curChar = Array(i)
        If (Char.IsLetterOrDigit(curChar)) Then
            Array(i) = Chr(Asc(curChar) + 1)
        End If
    Next

    ''Conver the array back to string''
    Dim newString As String = New String(Array)

    ''Hide the details form when book inventory runs''
    Me.Hide()

    ''display inventory form''
    frmInventory.Show()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For clarification, the user enters in

> Dim Title As String
>      Dim Author As String
>      Dim Stock As Integer
>      Dim Price As Double
>      Dim Fiction As String
>      Dim NonFiction As String

You then you search for the data do the file "C:\Users\Books.txt"?

Because, assuming you are the one who has added all the books to the text file, and assuming that you put each book on its own line with the same properties, i.e.

book title, author, price, etc
next book, .... and so on

then I don't see why you wouldn't do something like this...

```
  'Storing All Book Information Into One Object
   Public Structure BookDetails
       Dim Title As String
       Dim Author As String
       Dim Stock As Integer
       Dim Price As Double
       Dim Fiction As String
       Dim NonFiction As String
     End Structure
   sub ... 
    Dim theObjContents as new ArrayList
   Using objReader as new StreamReader("C:\Users\Books.txt")


    while objReader.endofstream = false
      theObjContents.add(objReader.readline)
    end while

   End Using        

    For each line in theObjContents
   'Check what you want
       if bookdetails.Title = line.split(whatever your delimiting character is").item(0)

    next
 end sub
```

I am not sure if that answers anything at all, please let me know if I am totally off on what you wanted.