# Drag textfile and open file in Textfile

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, listbox

I was trying to make a C# program that has a listbox and a button. What I want to do is to drag a text file that contains a group of pipe-delimited strings (e.g., `test|2|3|4|1`) and display the file contents in the listbox. The button would be used to clear the listbox.  Can somebody recommend how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

For drag and drop you can do this:

```
// Drag and Drop Files to Listbox
private void listBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, false))
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
    else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
}

private void listBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false);
    foreach (string fileName in files)
    {
       listBox1.Items.Add(fileName);  
    }
}
```

For reading textfile you can go through this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12967418/read-information-from-text-file-and-display-in-listbox)

Comment: this only puts the filepath of the textfile. What i am trying to achieve is when i drag the text file to the listbox, the data inside the textbox will be displayed in the listbox.

Comment: For that I gave you the below solution.